# Alternative to Sybase @@setrowcount in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sybase

The reason for my question is that I'm using SSMA for migration from Sybase to MS SQL Server and one of the main issues is that the "identifier `@@setrowcount` can not be converted". The `@@setrowcount` is currently used in all triggers.

I need to rewrite the triggers, but my intention is to change the triggers as little as possible.

In the end of all the triggers for (insert/update/delete) there is:

```
 SELECT @LocalVaraible = @@setrowcount 
 SET ROWCOUNT 0
 SET ROWCOUNT @LocalVariable
```

To be honest, I do not fully understand the purpose of setting the rowcount to 0 and the changing it back to the current sessions rowcount setting. Those triggers where created 20+ years ago, and the documentation is poor and there is no people left to ask about the purpose. Since I don't fully understand it, I was trying to find a easy way to just re-write as is.

However, @@Rowcount is not the same, since it only contains the rows affected by the last query and is reset by commands that don't access rows, such as IF-statements.

In Sybase there is a global variable called `@@setrowcount` which contains the current `SET ROWCOUNT` setting for the current session. I'm not able to find a similar function in MS SQL server 2022. Does one exist? If not, how do I get the current `SET ROWCOUNT` setting for the current session in MS SQL Server 2022?

Comment: BTW, `SET ROWCOUNT` is deprecated in SQL Server and you should not be using it. So... why are you wanting to use it?

Comment: Ask what you really want instead of using examples in unrelated products. Sybase and SQL Server forked 30 years ago and few people even know about it, much less used it. In fact, if you google for the actual question, eg `return row count in SQL Server` you may find the answer in the very first answer: `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: If you want to return to return only the first few rows, use either the properietary `TOP N` or the standard compliant `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY`. That works on PostgreSQL, MySQL and other databases as well. The SQL standard doesn't require `OFFSET` but SQL Server does

Comment: BTW now I remember that I *might* have seen `SET ROWCOUNT` 30 years ago, back when `TOP` couldn't be parameterized. I don't think I've seen this in the last 15 years, if not more

Comment: Is the whole three-statement block together, or is SET ROWCOUNT @LocalVariable performed in the end of the trigger? The whole block together is a NOP, but splitted it means that if code outside of trigger limited number of rows to add, the trigger's own code will always perform all rows. It's basically a workaround for global setting that shouldn't affect trigger's logic

Comment: I would say the sql server equavalent is something like: `SELECT @LocalVariable = row_count FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @@spid; SET ROWCOUNT 0; -- Do stuff... SET ROWCOUNT @LocalVariable`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just a reminder that the order of results from a search engine is not the same for every user.

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks for the help, the whole block is together so it is indeed a NOP. The query you wrote will solve my problem anyhow, so thanks:)